# How to get a general function pointer as a private member of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, boost

In the game I'm making, there will be triggers. When the trigger collides with anything, something will happen; If it is a door trigger, then the player will get moved to a new area. If it's an explosion trigger, and explosion happens. A chair trigger may make the player sit down.

I don't want to subclass each and every trigger. Each one shares enough important info, and each would activate using a common interface. The only difference between them is the routine that is called on collision.

The problem is the functions themselves may have differing signatures.

For example, the move player function requires a few things.

```
void move_player(Environment *new_env, Player *player, int new_x, int new_y)
```

But an explosion trigger may just be

```
void explode()
```

I need a class that accepts a `move_player` and a `explode`.

Here's what I think the pseudo code should look like

```
class Trigger
{
    public:
        Trigger(function_pointer f) { fp = f; }
        void activate() { fp(); }

    private:
        func_pointer fp;
}
```

I was thinking initializing/using it would look something like this.

```
auto f = std::bind(move_player, new_environment, my_player, 0, 0);
Trigger tigger (f);
tigger.activate();
```

I've tried going into std documentation and searching around other forums, along with checking out Boost documentation. I know how to use bind, and I'm pretty sure it should work here, but I have no how to set up the function pointer within the class to be of one indifferent to argument lists. A minimum working example would be awesome.

Comment: If you don't know what parameters it takes, how will you call it?

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: Based on your description, my initial thought is that you should set up a virtual 'Trigger' base class and then look into polymorphism techniques to create new classes that inherit their properties from Trigger.

Comment: Sorry Trent, but I definitely don't want to subclass each and every trigger I may potentially create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::function` in combination with `std::bind` and variadic templates like the example below:

```
class Trigger {
  std::function<void()> fp;
public:
  template<typename F, typename ...Args>
  Trigger(F f, Args... args) : fp(std::bind(f, args...)) { }
  void activate() { fp(); }
};
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/959c85546b27eaa8)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use here is [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). More concretely, an `std::function<void()>`. Also consider using a lambda instead of bind:

```
auto f = [=]() { movie_player(new_environment, my_player, 0, 0); };
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it may be possible to solve this using `std::function` and `std::bind` and/or lambda functions, that's just compiler and template magic for creating your own class - if you are keen on template magic, then by all means go for it. But I find that it doesn't really solve any problem [that needs solving], and makes the code harder to follow and debug (because you WILL sooner or later want to debug your move player trigger, most likely - at least unless you are a MUCH cleverer person than me and can write code that NEVER needs debugging). Setting a breakpoint in `std::function::operator()` is quite hard to get right and only break when you want, and not when it's called from some other place (e.g. your std::string lower-case converting function that deals with the user-input). .

In this case, I'd say a `Trigger` class with a virtual function would be the right thing.

The `MovePlayer` [or if you want to call it `move_player`] class would perhaps look like this:

```
class MovePlayer : public Trigger
{
   MovePlayer(Player *p, int x, int y) : player(p), dx, dy) {}
   void Activate() override { player->SetPos(dx, dy); }
private:
   Player *player;
   int dx, dy;
};
```

[Of course, you should not use raw pointers - in this case, use `std::shared_ptr<Player>` and store `std::weak_ptr<Player>` in your `MovePlayer`]

Comment: Points for explanation and perspective

Comment: I'm not unfamiliar with polymorphism, but I would like to avoid rampant subclassing. You have a point in debugging, but another guy has the solution I need. I suppose the next thing I need to worry about is where to put the functions I may need to send the triggers. Thanks for showing me weak and shared_ptrs. I've been using just plain 'ol pointers so far.

Comment: My point is that "under the hood", it will still be subclassing [or something like it], just that it happens inside some template code that you have no control over - so you are just saving a little bit of typing [maybe].